# stop user from being runing any commands, should able to run only granted with sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, redhat-enterprise-linux

Is there any single command or script which gives result, the list of how many commands a linux user is able to execute?

And how to stop user from executing even a linux basic commands and should not able to run any shell scripts.

Comment: If you just want to stop users to run basic commands, you can take away the permission to execute commands you don't want users to run on /bin/<command> but this may break a lot of things. (So instead of the commands being rwxr-xr-x (and owned by root/root) you can change it to rwxr-xr-- so no one else but root or those in root group can execute them.. but it may cause issues (haven't tried it myself so I can't tell you if it will break anything)

Comment: Take a look at restricted shell.

Comment: Do u have idea about any specific parameters in restricted shell?

Comment: Hi Darius, I have tried that and also tried setfacl and getfacl, implemented on /usr/bin but still few commands like pwd, vim, etc. are working, cause location is /bin. My main purpose is, If I have given permission to execute only 2 commands then apart from that user A should not able to execute any other commands. Same if user B is allowed to execute other 2 commands, should able to execute only those two commands. Thanks.